# Accessing a webpage from an ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, ip, limit

I'm trying to access and get page source code of another website from my ASP.NET site, I'm using WebClient or HttpWebRequest right now but I might change that.

I'm wondering if a user visits my page and then the page calls another site, then who's IP will be registered at the external site? My server's IP or my User's IP? I've done some testing, so far it seems like it would be the user's IP.

The site I'm going to be accessing would detect too many visits from the same IP, that's why I don't want it to be my server's IP that accesses it.
Would it be safer to make an App instead of a website to do this, to make sure that my server doesn't get blocked from their site?

Comment: Why does the other website potentially block access if it all comes from a single IP address? Would you not be complying with their terms of use by scraping their site?

Answer (score 0):

The remote site will get a request from your server-side code, so it will register the request using your server's IP address.